# Klarna payment not show on frontend magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, klarna

i'm stuck on this issue

Klarna payment not show on frontend magento 2.4.3 ( i tried on clean shop )

I enabled it, config with right credentials, enable log, and all log look fine

But on fronend it not show

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

LOG

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you checked/try in default luma theme ?

Comment: yes, i checked, still not show, it's clean shop, i just install, than config klarna

Comment: Should enable "Logging" & "Request Logging" from module to check in more details..

Comment: yes, klarna log on backend look fine, 204 for post, and 200 for get, i don't see anything on magento log

Comment: I added log image on my post, can you have a look @Pawan ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your store to 2.4.3-p1?  There apparently are fixes for Klarna,  Braintree etc in the new update.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/2-4-3-p1.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried, klarna still not show on frontend :(